# When using dplyr, at which step should I send the data to a data.table() for optimal performance?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Most of the time, the beginning of a code I'm working on looks something like this:

```
data = read.csv("path") %>% 
  filter() %>% 
  select() %>% 
  mutate() %>% 

  data.table()
```

Am I losing performance by sending the data to a data.table() only at the last step?

Comment: all of the steps can be done with data.table and typically they're all faster with data.table

Comment: As an addition to @MichaelChirico 's comment: Have a look at the `fread` function from `library(data.table)` to start with a data.table object right away.

Comment: and/or use setDT(), in stead of data.table()

Comment: https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out that you can do all of that in data.table or in the tidyverse.  Given you seem more comfortable in dplyr is there a reason that you want to use data.table in your code?

A good reason is that you have a performance problem.  If dplyr is running slow then you could move everything to data.table and fread.  If there really isn't a reason, perhaps just convert the data to tibble in the last line for consistency.

If you want a more robust answer on performance profiling, you should probably post something more specific and reproducible.